# Jenkins Multiconfiguration Build for multiple OS on the same machine?

Tags: jenkins

I am just starting to learn both Jenkins and continuous Delivery. I have both books.

I was just wondering the following. I am building my application for both Mac and Windows. Although I only have an OSX Machine available with virtualBox with windows.

Can i get jenkins to use my virtual machine and my ox machine for the test at the same time?

Or is it that when one want to run test on different os, he needs to provide node/label understood as other machines that hold theses Operating systems respectively. Can't jenkins launch or connect to a virtual machine on the same OS ?

As a plus, could someone let me know, how would it be possible to do it on cloudBees ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your virtual machine a different IP address from your Mac and set it up as a separate slave node in Jenkins. Jenkins will treat them as totally different machines.